# How to extract a xhtml meetgrid section using a XSLTranformation?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I would like to extract data from a website, transform it (using xsl) and get an output in XML. 
Why does my xsl not transformation the XML to get the desired output?

The **XML** I am using to test the transformation is below:

```
 <?xml version= "1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="diverecorder.xsl"?>
    <head> 
    <body> 
      <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
          <br/><h3>2015</h3>
          <table class="meetgrid" summary="List of Meets">
            <tr><td>Mar 08</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=486">Manifestazione Regionale Cat. C4 – C2 –C1 - R</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Mar 07</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=484">Diving SA State Age Open &amp; Synchro 2015</a></td></tr>
          </table>
          <br /><h3>2014</h3>
          <table class="meetgrid" summary="List of Meets">
            <tr><td>Dec 13</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=461">Sheffield Santa Skills 2014</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Dec 11</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=460">2014/15 Australian Open Championships</a></td></tr>
          </table>
    </html>
```

This is coming directly from a website, apart from the edited top three lines to connect to diverecorder.xsl file to test the xsl transformation. The information will repeat same as the sample, with the main change being the number after "mref=".

Below is the **XSL** code I am using to try to exact the meetgrid and h3 sections from the website and transform it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 xmlns:soap="http://soap/envelope/">

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="body/div">
                            <event>
                                <xsl:for-each select="div">
                                    <xsl:if test="h3">
                                        <yearRange>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(.), ' ', ',')" />
                                        </yearRange>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="@class='meetgrid'">
                                        <eventmonthDay>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="tr/td" />
                                        </eventmonthDay>                                                
                                        <eventUrl>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(a/@href, '/event/')" />/download/<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(a/@href, '/event/')" />multi/
                                        </eventUrl>
                                        <eventTitle>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="/a" />
                                        </eventTitle>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </event>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **Current Output** is Choose Meet.

**Expected/Desired Output** that currently I don't get.

```
<head>
   <body>
     <year>
     2015
     </year>
    <eventmonthday>Mar 08</eventmonthday><event>Manifestazione Regionale Cat. C4 – C2 –C1 - R</event> 
    <eventmonthday>Mar 07</eventmonthday><event>Diving SA State Age Open &amp; Synchro 2015</event>
    ...
     <year>
     2014
     </year>
    <eventmonthday>Dec 13</eventmonthday><event>Sheffield Santa Skills 2014</event>
    <eventmonthday>Dec 11</eventmonthday><event>2014/15 Australian Open Championships</event>
    ...
   </body>
</head>
```

Notes: 
The full source of what I am trying to extract is view-source:http://www.diverecorder.co.uk/meetexplorer/selectmeet.php

The test I am using to see if the transformation is working is - create diverecorder.xml and diverecorder to xsl and run the xml file in Internet Explorer to check if the transformation worked properly.

Similar questions I have looked at but I couldn't work out the solution include: 
[How to extract a div section from one xhtml document into another xhtml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097063/how-to-extract-a-div-section-from-one-xhtml-document-into-another-xhtml-document)

[Extracting data from website with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202489/extracting-data-from-website-with-xslt)

[How to replace a text in XML file using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375840/how-to-replace-a-text-in-xml-file-using-xslt)

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Please read the help on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay thank you, I read them both and revised the question.

Comment: I still don't understand most of your question, but clearly  `<xsl:for-each select="docRoot/div">` does not do anything, because there is no `docRoot` element in your input.

Comment: I changed it to <xsl:for-each select=body/div"> but am still not getting an output. I guess I am trying to find out where the xsl is broken as my current xsl is not giving me my desired output. The other questions are explaining where I think the problem is (I believe its something wrong with translate(normalize-space...) as now it is going to the correct path body/div/div/h3 or body/div/div/meetgrid and is still not outputting what I would like

Comment: You are still not getting an output, because: (1) all your input document elements are in the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` **namespace**; you must define a **prefix** for this namespace and use it when addressing the elements; (2) `<xsl:template match="body">` would put you in the context of `body` - and then <xsl:for-each select=body/div"> selects nothing because `body` has no child `body`.

Comment: And your question is still not clear: I suggest you put some recognizable data in your example input, and show us the same data in your required output. And show your required output as the actual XML or HTML **code** that you expect to get.

Comment: Hopefully the question is more clear now. I added the namespace, changed the template match to "/" and changed example input and required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hopefully the question is more clear now. I added the namespace,
>   changed the template match to "/" and changed example input and
>   required output.

Unfortunately, your input is still not well-formed XML, because (1) it is missing closing tags for the `body` and the two `div` elements and (2) it contains an undeclared entity `&nbsp;`.

In the interest of moving this forward:

Given a **well-formed input** such as:

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head/>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
        <br/>
        <h3>2015</h3>
        <table class="meetgrid" summary="List of Meets">
          <tr>
            <td>Mar 08</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=486">Manifestazione Regionale Cat. C4 – C2 –C1 - R</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mar 07</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=484">Diving SA State Age Open &amp; Synchro 2015</a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h3>2014</h3>
        <table class="meetgrid" summary="List of Meets">
          <tr>
            <td>Dec 13</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=461">Sheffield Santa Skills 2014</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dec 11</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="selectevent.php?mref=460">2014/15 Australian Open Championships</a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the folowing **stylesheet**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="x">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="x:html/x:body/x:div/x:div/x:table">
                <year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::x:h3[1]"/>
                </year>
                <xsl:for-each select="x:tr">
                    <eventmonthday>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:td[1]"/>
                    </eventmonthday>
                    <event>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:td[2]/x:a"/>
                    </event> 
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:for-each> 
       </body>
    </head>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<head>
   <body>
      <year>2015</year>
      <eventmonthday>Mar 08</eventmonthday>
      <event>Manifestazione Regionale Cat. C4 ‚Äì C2 ‚ÄìC1 - R</event>
      <eventmonthday>Mar 07</eventmonthday>
      <event>Diving SA State Age Open &amp; Synchro 2015</event>
      <year>2014</year>
      <eventmonthday>Dec 13</eventmonthday>
      <event>Sheffield Santa Skills 2014</event>
      <eventmonthday>Dec 11</eventmonthday>
      <event>2014/15 Australian Open Championships</event>
   </body>
</head>
```

---

### Note:

Some processors (e.g. Saxon) are capable of processing a document that contains HTML entities without declaring them explicitly, but pointing to a specific DTD instead, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

They will decode the entities by consulting the actual DTD document found at the URL in the DOCTYPE declaration. In my tests, this was **very** slow.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and help. The above is what I was trying to produce. I should be able to finish off the rest of the hyperlinks inside the page on my own now.